ECS task container exited with code 1 without any logs
I have an ECS service. The only task in the service exited with code 1. The container just runs for 10 secs and the logs just show basic spring boot logs.
Assumed it could be CPU/memory resource constraints and increasing it did not help. The application runs fine in local. Appreciate any help!

Have you tried increasing the Spring Boot log level?
